# Uploading two images on same controller but image name of second file takes first file name

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

[image]

[image]

Codeigniter File :

```
            if (!empty($_FILES['left_full_image']['name']))             
            {

                $uploaded_file_name = $_FILES['left_full_image']['name'];                   
                $extension = pathinfo($uploaded_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $uploaded_file_name_withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $uploaded_file_name);
                $filename = time().$uploaded_file_name_withoutExt;
                $this->load->library('common');

                $upload_sts = $this->common->global_file_upload($path, 'left_full_image', $filename);

                if (isset($upload_sts['success']) && $upload_sts['success'] == 'y') {
                    if (isset($upload_sts['data']['full_path']) && file_exists($upload_sts['data']['full_path'])) {
                        $data['hd_left_full_image'] = $path.$filename.'.'.$extension;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!empty($_FILES['right_highlight_image']['name']))           
            {

                $uploaded_file_name = $_FILES['right_highlight_image']['name'];
                $extension = pathinfo($uploaded_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $uploaded_file_name_withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $uploaded_file_name);
                $filename = time().$uploaded_file_name_withoutExt;
                $this->load->library('common');
                $upload_sts = $this->common->global_file_upload($path,'right_highlight_image',$filename);                   
                if (isset($upload_sts['success']) && $upload_sts['success'] == 'y') {
                    if (isset($upload_sts['data']['full_path']) && file_exists($upload_sts['data']['full_path'])) {
                        $data['hd_right_highlight_image'] = $path.$filename.'.'.$extension;
                    }
                }
            }
```

While I try to upload this both the file in the same form both the files got uploaded , but the file name of first uploaded file is not cleared while the second file got uploaded .

The second file also got the same name of first name .

**Name of First file : **1500695786default_left****

```
Array ( [success] => y [data] => Array ( **[file_name] => 1500695786default_left.jpg** [file_type] => image/jpeg [file_path] => /home/content/17/10326617/html/display/ci_ontime2/asset/upload/ [full_path] => /home/content/17/10326617/html/display/ci_ontime2/asset/upload/1500695786default_left.jpg [raw_name] => 1500695786default_left [orig_name] => 1500695786default_left.jpg [client_name] => default_left.jpg [file_ext] => .jpg [file_size] => 31.62 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 626 [image_height] => 626 [image_type] => jpeg [image_size_str] => width="626" height="626" ) )
```

**Second Image Name : **1500695786comingsoon1****

```
Array ( [success] => y [data] => Array ( **[file_name] => 1500695786default_left.png** [file_type] => image/png [file_path] => /home/content/17/10326617/html/display/ci_ontime2/asset/upload/ [full_path] => /home/content/17/10326617/html/display/ci_ontime2/asset/upload/1500695786default_left.png [raw_name] => 1500695786default_left [orig_name] => 1500695786default_left.png **[client_name] => comingsoon1.png** [file_ext] => .png [file_size] => 37.11 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 256 [image_height] => 256 [image_type] => png [image_size_str] => width="256" height="256" ) )
```

Befor uploading while I print the name of second image it shows as 1500695786comingsoon1 but once after uploading the image if I print the result of uploaded status it shows the name of first image only the extension has been changed that the second images has . But in the second image upload status I can get the original image name in [client_name] => comingsoon1.png but not in file name .

Could any one help me what actual goes wrong here .

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your variables but besides that. I think your HTML just uses the same fieldnames. Without the source its guessing for us here.

Also, your '$uploaded_file_name_withoutExt' is not needed. You can just do: **basename**($myfilename); http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php or even the method **pathinfo** that you already are using can return that filename without extension.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php. No need to regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using same variable name `$filename` in both condition.

replace

```
$filename = time().$uploaded_file_name_withoutExt;
```

to

```
$filename_firstImage = time().$uploaded_file_name_withoutExt;
```

Use different variable name